# Smooth css change transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've setup a jQuery function that changes the body background colour when a certain div comes into view, e.g. the body background colour is black, when `#block-three` (that contains black text), the body background colour changes to white, and changes back when this goes out of view. This works fine, it's just very sudden though, I'm looking for a much smoother transition between background colours, fading between colours as you scroll (if possible).
jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/TB53d/ 
HTML:

```
<div id="block-one" class="block">
    <div class="inner-block">Test</div>
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
</div>
<div id="block-two" class="block">
    <div class="inner-block">Test</div>
</div>
<div id="block-three" class="block">
    <div class="inner-block">Test</div>
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
</div>
<div id="block-four" class="block">
    <div class="inner-block">Test</div>
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
</div>
<div id="block-five" class="block">
    <div class="inner-block">Test</div>
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var blockHeight = [];
$(".block").each(function () {
    blockHeight.push($(this).height());
});

function hoverCurrentItem() {
    var sIndex = 0;
    var totalHeight = 0;
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    for (var i in blockHeight) {
        totalHeight += blockHeight[i];
        if (totalHeight > scrolled) {
            break;
        } else {
            sIndex++;
        }
    }

    var $sItem = $(".block").eq(sIndex);
    if (!$sItem.hasClass("selected")) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $sItem.addClass("selected");
    }
    if ($("#block-three").hasClass("selected")) {
        $("body").css("background-color", "white");
    } else {
        $("body").css("background-color", "black");
    }
}
hoverCurrentItem();

$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    hoverCurrentItem()
});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `transition` with CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    transition:all 1s;
}
```

The **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TB53d/1/)**

Comment: Prefer CSS `transition` as it is immensely more efficient and CPU-friendly. The difference between CSS `transition` and jQuery `animate()` is like the difference between "would you kindly change this smoothly" and "GRAGH YOU ----ING MORON CHANGE THE COLOUR RIGHT ----ING NOW!"... if you catch my drift. That said, prefer `transition:background-color 1s;` if you know which properties you want to animate.